# Pandas RMSE Groupby Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am trying to compute the RMSE of a panda dataframe based on multiple conditions: (plant_name, year, month). My datafram (df3m) looks like this:

```
  plant_name  year  month    obsvals  modelvals
0  ARIZONA I  2021      1   8.900582   8.298038
1  ARIZONA I  2021      2   7.976660   7.410446
2  ARIZONA I  2021      3  10.803689  11.480000
3  CAETITE I  2021      1   9.104309   7.778750
4  CAETITE I  2021      2   6.054558   6.022783
```

I have tried grouping by plant_name, year, month and then applyting "mean_squared_error" using

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

My one line code for attempting this looks like this...maybe I need to define a function here instead?

```
rmse = df3m.groupby(['plant_name']) 
[['obsvals','modelvals']].mean_squared_error(squared = False) #for rmse use "False"
```

Using the above i get this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mean_squared_error'
```

My final output should look like:

```
plant_name      year       rmse 
0   ARIZONA I   2021         ? 
1   CAETITE I   2021         ?
```

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.GroupBy.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and put the call to `mean_squared_error` inside it, as follows:

```
df_out = (df3m.groupby(['plant_name','year','month'])[['obsvals','modelvals']]
              .apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x['obsvals'], x['modelvals'], squared=False))
         ).to_frame(name='rmse').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

  plant_name  year  month      rmse
0  ARIZONA I  2021      1  0.602544
1  ARIZONA I  2021      2  0.566214
2  ARIZONA I  2021      3  0.676311
3  CAETITE I  2021      1  1.325559
4  CAETITE I  2021      2  0.031775
```

### Edit

As per the edit of the question to get the expected result with `plant_name` and `year` only, we can modify the codes above to exclude the grouping by `month`, as follows:

```
df_out2 = (df3m.groupby(['plant_name','year'])[['obsvals','modelvals']]
              .apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x['obsvals'], x['modelvals'], squared=False))
         ).to_frame(name='rmse').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df_out2)

  plant_name  year      rmse
0  ARIZONA I  2021  0.616726
1  CAETITE I  2021  0.937581
```